# DateComponentsFormatter not working with dates far in the past

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I am using the built in DateComponentsFormatter to figure out the number of years between the current day and another date. If the date gets too far in the past for example 1940, the returned units are wrong:

```
let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: 1940, month: 1, day: 2, hour: 1, minute: 1, second: 1)

let date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!

let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.year]
dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .full

print(dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: abs(date.timeIntervalSinceNow)))
```

This prints `-58 years` which is incorrect. Is this an Apple bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `print(dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: date, to: Date()) ?? "")`

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks I had also tried that which is better but doesn't always give the same value... Sometimes 70 years, sometimes 69 years

Comment: it gives me 77 years

Comment: You might be having a problem with eras?

Comment: @LeoDabus Sorry was using a different date. That works okay for dates in the past but if you do dates far in the future, that's when it is giving the different values. Try using 2088 instead of 1940. It will occasionally show 69 instead of 70 if you print it like 10 times in a row

Comment: @DuncanC how would I solve this?

Comment: @Stephen it gives me "-70 years\n" when using 2088 every single time. BTW adding the era component won't make a difference

Comment: @LeoDabus Hmm I'm also switching (from: date, to: Date()) to (from: Date(), to: date) as I always want it to be positive. I'm on Xcode 8.3.3, Swift 3.1 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in `DateComponentsFormatter`'s implementation. 
They apparently are using Int32 internally to represent time intervals.

I ran into the same issue, it's very easy to reproduce:

```
let interval: TimeInterval = ... some number here
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.second]
formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
print(formatter.string(from: interval) ?? "")
```

This is supposed to output just the number of seconds, without any special calculations.
Even that only works as expected up until 2147483647 (which happens to be Int32.max). Everything over that simply overflows and produces incorrect results.

This maximum "supported" number of seconds is 68y 2w 4d 3h 14m 7s, which explains why you are seeing it also.

**UPD**

Someone already filed a radar: http://www.openradar.me/32513237 and mentioned a workaround there, and it works!

In your case that would be instead using:

```
let date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
let now = Date()
dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: date, to: now)
```